# Cant pass local object to nested partial in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, partial-views

Im hoping that someone can shed light on what is probably a simple mistake. Im trying to pass a local variable, article, which is in the partial _article.html.erb, to another partial nested within _article.html.erb.  When the partial code is in _article.html.erb, it works fine.I've tried many variations (including :locals) but cant seem to pass the local variable.

_article.html.erb

```
 <% if current_user.favorited?(article) %>     
            <%= render :partial => 'unfavorite', :object => article  %>
 <% else %>
            <%= render :partial => 'favorite', :object => article %>
 <% end %>
```

_favorite.html.erb (both favorite and unfavorite are more or less the same, so I've only posted one)

```
 <%= form_for current_user.favorites.find_by_article_id(article), :html => { :method => :delete,  :class => 'unfavorite_form', }, :remote => true do |f| %> 
            <div><%= f.hidden_field :article_id %></div>
            <%= image_submit_tag("vote-favorite-on.png", :alt => "Favorite", :id => "favorites_button", :title => "Remove from favorites") %> 
 <% end %>
```

The error message is:

```
       undefined local variable or method `article' for #<#<Class:0x491c2b0>:0x6727a58>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rails docs for [rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) mention the use of object like this:

```
<%= render :partial => "customer", :object => @new_customer %>
```

And say that:

```
Within the customer partial, the customer variable will refer to @new_customer from the parent view.
```

Which makes it seem like the :object variable is translated into the name of the partial.  So in your case, in _favorite, you'd have to use the favorite variable:

```
 <%= form_for current_user.favorites.find_by_article_id(favorite), :html => { :method => :delete,  :class => 'unfavorite_form', }, :remote => true do |f| %>
```

Personally I prefer the locals syntax, because then you can be explicit:

```
<%= render :partial => 'favorite', :locals => {:article => article} %>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked though I was positive I tried it before posting.