# ruby on rails shared error message cannot define method or object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been reading through the ruby on rails tutorial by michael hartl, and i'm at where I am trying to post microposts.  I'm trying to render an error message within the form, and the book says to assign f.object to object. It keeps giving me the error that "object" is an undefined local variable or method. Here is the code:

shared/_error_messages.html.erb

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
        The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
        <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li>* <%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div><% end %>
```

shared/_post_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
 <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
   <div class="field">
<%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new post..." %>
   </div>
 <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

The answer below is incorrect. See the comments for details.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

I'm not sure what Hartl's tutorial says, but `f.object` is not defined on the form, which I assume is where the error is coming from (please post the error itself for clarity).

Changing this line:

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
```

to

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f %>
```

Should fix the problem. Basically you want to pass the form `f` to the partial, with the name `object` -- that's what the option `object: f` does. (You could actually name it anything you want, as long as you use the same naming inside your partial. There's nothing special about the name `object` in this context.)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I did that and then it continues to another error saying undefined method 'errors'   the orginial errors says 'undefined local variable or method `object' for #<#<Class:0x40f7478>:0x3b038f8>' in line 1 of _error_messages.html.erb

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, `object` is a valid method of the generated form. Can you point to exactly where in Hartl's tutorial you are getting this code from?

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem. Try changing your `render` call to `render partial: 'shared/error_messages', locals: { object: f }`.

Comment: yes, it started on listing 10.31 from this tutorial book http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts#sec-showing_microposts only difference is I called it posts instead of micropost. from what i can see anyway

Comment: Hmm... strange, I don't see any difference.

Comment: The Rails documentation specifies: `Also note that explicitly specifying :partial is required when passing additional options such as :layout.` See the original [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#partial-layouts).

Comment: i've tried <%= render partial: 'shared/error_messages', locals: { object: f } %>
still not working, same error.

Comment: Sorry, that should be `f.object` not `f`. So: `render partial: 'shared/error_messages', locals: { object: f.object }`. But if you're getting the same error then I'm guessing that won't work either.

Comment: if i skip the render part and just straight up put the whole code wherever error messages are needed it works

Comment: Yes the problem is the passing of `object` from the view to the partial, which for some reason isn't working.

Comment: actually its not from the view to the partial.  its from the view to a partial to another partial.  it starts from view/static/home.html which renders to the shared/_post_form and then renders to shared/_error_messsages.  does this help at all?

Comment: maybe relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731318/cant-pass-local-object-to-nested-partial-in-rails-3 I think the use of `object` is problematic, because rails uses that option to mean something else (not sure why Hartl chose to use it this way). What if you change `object: f.object` to `obj: f.object` and then in your partial swap all instances of `object` for `obj`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot pass a `@post` form controller. Where controller are you in when you render partial `_post_form.html.erb` ? Check if you don't have a `@post = current_user.posts.build` in that controller, add it.

Comment: '@post' is under static controller, where I render the partial '_post_form.html.erb'.  just like you said under def home '@post = current_user.posts.build' is posted there.